# Monero margin trading on Poloniex and BitMEX

Tags: poloniex

Please help clarify the Poloniex margin rules for the following:

1. What equity percentage is needed when taking out a Monero loan?
2. At what equity percentage are margin called issued?
3. Can loan principle be repaid early with proceeds from a new loan offered at a lower rate?
4. If I loan Monero what percentage of loan fees do I need to surender to Poloniex?

How do the above margin procedures compare with those of BitMEX? In particular how do the liquidation and "Dynamic Profit Equalisation" rules of BitMEX differ from Poloniex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to just put a link to Poloniex's documentation, as pasting it here wholesale would be too much copy to be considered fair use (and it has formatting and images, and might change in the future):

https://poloniex.com/support/aboutMarginTrading/

And, one word of warning: margin is high risk, high reward. Keyword being "risk".

Comment: Also, storing funds on an exchange is also high risk.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this counts as an answer to your question, but bitmex.com allows leverage/margin trading and has a good documentation on it https://www.bitmex.com/app/tradingOverview

BitMEX started accepting XMR just a few days ago and I have no personal experience with them. Additionally the warning from the post by user36303 applies here too.

Comment: I updated my question to request a comparison between the margin rules of Poloniex and BitMEX